# How to resolve error when connect Hawkbit with MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, hawkbit

I'm trying to config Hawkbit following this guide: https://www.eclipse.org/hawkbit/guides/runhawkbit/

- In pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

- In application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/{SCHEMA_NAME}
spring.datasource.username={USER_NAME}
spring.datasource.password={PWD}
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
```

But I got this error: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YDtFKxF4Vv/

How to resolve this?

Comment: an intial look at the error, which should be part of this question rather than in pastebin, looks totally unrelated to MariaDB. `Validate failed: Detected failed migration to version 1.0.1` seems to be the important bit.

Comment: @danblack, I cannot investigate the exact problem. When I remove the config related to MariaDB, I can run Hawkbit normally

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late, but basically the Hawkbit server has database migration scripts (Flyway). Within the HawkBit database, there is a table reserved for tracking these migrations for backwards compatibility. This is the `schema_version` table.

The problem that you see here is that Flyway is trying to migrate the state of the database, but fails because it detects a previous migration that failed.

```
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed: Detected failed migration to version 1.0.1 (init   )
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.doValidate(Flyway.java:1482)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.access$100(Flyway.java:85)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1364)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1356)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1711)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1356)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
    ... 98 common frames omitted
```

Easiest solution would be to start with a fresh database. **But** in the case that you have important data in the database, you could also truncate the `schema_version` table and rerun the Hawkbit server.